# Firefox doesn't show svg image

Tags: firefox, svg

I have a very strange problem with a SVG file in Firefox. It's about the logo in the header on this page: [dyncheck.de](https://dyncheck.de)

It is displayed correctly in all browsers except Firefox. But only in the page header. In the footer it is there, even in Firefox. It can also be found correctly in the source code, but the inspector tells me it has size zero.

Does anyone have an explanation for this and maybe a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give your image a width

Comment: And put an [mcve] in your question because once you have the solution, you'll fix your site and this question will be of no value to anyone else.

Comment: The width I also tried before, but that doesn't help. And in the footer the image is displayed in FF without a width too.

Answer (score 2):

As I've commented:you need to give a width to your image in CSS

What happens is that the header image is in a flexbox layout and your svg image is collapsed to a 0 width like so:

```css
header,footer{border:1px solid; margin:1em;}
header{display:flex;}
```

```html
<header>
  <div><img src="https://dyncheck.de/images/herpolsheimer-neutral-logo-anthrazit.svg" alt="HERPOLSHEIMER innovativ GmbH &amp; Co. KG Logo"></div>
  <div>header</div>
</header>
<footer>
  <div><img src="https://dyncheck.de/images/herpolsheimer-neutral-logo-anthrazit.svg" alt="HERPOLSHEIMER innovativ GmbH &amp; Co. KG Logo" style="width: 200px;"></div>
  <div>footer</div>
</footer>
```

Adding a width to the image is solving your problem:

```css
    header,footer{border:1px solid; margin:1em;}
    header{display:flex;}

    img{width:200px;}
```

```html
<header>
      <div><img src="https://dyncheck.de/images/herpolsheimer-neutral-logo-anthrazit.svg" alt="HERPOLSHEIMER innovativ GmbH &amp; Co. KG Logo"></div>
      <div>header</div>
    </header>
    <footer>
      <div><img src="https://dyncheck.de/images/herpolsheimer-neutral-logo-anthrazit.svg" alt="HERPOLSHEIMER innovativ GmbH &amp; Co. KG Logo" style="width: 200px;"></div>
      <div>footer</div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: Ok, i thought that you mean a html width, as it already has a CSS width, but in percent. And in the original site herpolsheimer.ag, where this is taken from, the image has no width and is displayed too. Very confusing